# R package comprable to the output from Daniel Soper's "Interaction"

Tags: r, regression, interaction

I am looking for an R-package that will both plot interactions (Aiken & West) and significance test each interaction line, like in the output from Daniel Soper's "Interaction" software. 
1) Is there such a package?
2) If not, how can I code in R to get significance testing for each interaction line's slope? I can get the plots fine in sJplot, so some code to supplement them with by significance testing the lines would be much appreciated.

Comment: In order to help you, it would be helpful to see full references and, ideally, a specific example with output.

Comment: Here is some example output, from the maker of the software: http://www.danielsoper.com/Interaction/stats.aspx 
What I am looking to emulate are the tests under the sections for individual interaction lines (Interaction Line 1, Interaction Line 2, Interaction Line 3). The full software information is located at http://www.danielsoper.com/Interaction/

Comment: What do you mean by "each interaction line"? This would be the p-value from each interaction term from the standard summary output, or not?